# Deserialize Uri to WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#, json, serialization, uwp

I serialized my Image like `Uri` and I have trouble with Deserialization

```
var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(temp[0].BackStage.AbsoluteUri);
 using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
 {
  await BackStageImg.SetSourceAsync(stream);
 }
```

This code doesnt work, it says "You dont have an access" when I try put `Uri` to `StorageFile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied my file to `App Local Folder` and pick like

```
StorageFile localFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/background"));
```